# How do I access my Ubuntu Server installed on Virtual box from anywhere in the World

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iot, portforwarding

I am trying to make an IOT using nodemcu and a LED. I want to access the Ubuntu Server(which is installed in the virtual box) through some other network(outside my LAN). How can I do it? I read many articles online, but I am not able to figure it out. I tried port forwarding but it did not work.

[image: Port Forward]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there's a problem in the port forwarding, or I am following a wrong method.

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on my laptop via VirtualBox. I have installed LAMP. Also, network set to bridged adapter, plus I have dynamic IP

As I logged in, I ran ifconfig. It gave me the inet address as 192.168.16.101

Comment: Generally speaking you want to do this via an intermediary server in the cloud, rather than allowing inbound external traffic onto your LAN.  You could use something like ngrok, or roll your own solution with a cloud VM to do the relay into a tunnel, or start hosting the VM you ultimately want to reach in the cloud.  For something as simple as controlling an LED you can simply pass messages via an MQTT broker or one of its alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the VM network interface to be NAT or Bridged?
If it is NAT, then you are essentially double NATTed which means you will need to port forward from your router to the VM host and then you will need to port forward from the host to the VM as the IP assigned will be local to the host machine.

However, the easiest is to set the VM network interface to Bridged.

This will mean the VM will be able access your network directly as it should be on the same subnet as your laptop and appear as another device, which your router will be able to port forward to.

Comment: Regardless of the VM settings, it's probable (and decidedly *hopeful*) that external traffic is not accepted for routing on to the LAN that holds the physical machine containing it.

Comment: I have many VMs that are exposed to a WAN in this exact way. What do you mean traffic is not accepted?

Comment: The asker seems to be asking from an amateur consumer perspective - beyond the VM settings, there are a lot of things that need to work right before they can get external requests into a LAN hanging off something like consumer Internet service (it's not even clear they've figured out the external IP) and a lot of reasons why **they should not try to enable that**.  The task of controlling an LED (or a real light) from outside the home really doesn't require it - bouncing messages off a cloud server like an MQTT broker will be a much more sound solution for such a limited need.

Comment: I have set my Virtual box on Bridged NAT, I have stated that in the question. The problem is I can't access it outside from my local network, even though I port forwarded my router. Is it essential to get a domain or static IP for this to work? (And sorry for the late reply).

Comment: Again, you really, really don't want to allow incoming traffic.  If you did, it would be a networking question off topic here.  What you should do is use a cloud messaging scheme (MQTT, etc) where everything except the cloud server makes *outbound* connections only; but that is *also* off-topic here.  What matters for the moment is that the issue has *nothing* to do with your VM software, and everything to do with a bad architectural idea you have *fortunately* not yet fully implemented.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes I agree. I was looking to answer the 'micro' problem as posed in the question and not looking at the larger problem which the OP is trying to solve.
Checkout https://cloudmqtt.com and https://www.instructables.com/id/NodeMCU-MQTT-Basic-Example/ for info and tutorials on nodeMCU and MQTT.